# Angular 4 - IE11 : font-awesome is not working with angular2-multiselect-dropdown on IE11

Tags: javascript, css, angular, internet-explorer, font-awesome

Under my **Angular 4.0.0** app , am using **angular2-multiselect-dropdown**:

[Official documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkGjx.png)

in my **package.json** am installing it with **font-awesome** , to get it work :

```
"angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.2.3",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
```

It goes well under all browsers exepte **IE11**

My scenario is the following :

- this is my **multiselect** :

[image]

When **selecting** an item , that goes well

But when **deselcting**  from the **X** icon :

[image]

that goes wrong under **IE 11** : simply it's not deselected , and any error is shown in the console , although the deselection goes well from the checkbox:

[image]

- The problem is *specifically* with the **X** icon when **deselection** under **IE11**

i have tried to use to add this tag in my head part in the **index.html** :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But that didn't work.

**Any suggestions ?**

Comment: It might be due to caching issues. There was a smilar question about this today : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47345705/8800147. Hope it helps

Comment: @Brice i ve tried that solution , but didn t work

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it with the upgrade of the **angular2-multiselect-dropdown** to the **1.3.6** version.

Just update it in the **package.json**

```
"angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "1.3.6",
```